# Auto increase variable

Tags: php, variables

i have a mysql table with 2 coloumns (firstname and lastname) and i want when i run the (select * from names) query all the values from firstname stored into an autoincrement variable like name1=john name2=george etc. and the same for lastname
surname1=williams surname2=james. i have written this but i cant get it to work

```
<?php
$name="";

$surname="";

$i =1;

$getinfo = "select * from names ";

$query = mysql_query($getinfo);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {


$name.$i. = $row['firstname'];
$surname.$i = $row['lastname'];




}

$i ++;

?>
```

Comment: Why don't you use array such as `$name[] = $row['firstname']` and `$surname[] = $row['lastname']` instead of trying to set multiple variables?

Comment: Sorry, but that is a _very_ strange request. You do know about the advantages of numeric arrays to hold such sequences?

Comment: i forgot the } i have it in my original code and i edited here as well. i dont want the array because i want to use the variables in a next step of my code. but if it is not possible i will find another way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve what you want, you will need to use this syntax:

```
$i = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    ${'name'.$i}    = $row['firstname'];
    ${'surname'.$i} = $row['lastname'];
    $i++;
}
```

But this is not a clean way to do so. I recommend you use arrays such as:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $names[]    = $row['firstname'];
    $surnames[] = $row['lastname'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but a pretty strange thing to do:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  ++$i;
  $nameKey='name'.$i;
  $surnameKey='name'.$i;
  $$nameKey = $row['firstname'];
  $$surnameKey = $row['lastname'];
}
```

Instead why don't you simply use numeric arrays?

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  $name[]    = $row['firstname'];
  $surname[] = $row['lastname'];
}
```

Or, even more elegant:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  $persons[] = [
    'name' => $row['firstname'],
    'surname' => $row['lastname']
  ];
}
```

Comment: @AgisSoleas Glad to hear that! (whatever it is you did...)